# Using a JSON from Flickr directly in return() or copy it using .slice? React beginner

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

I'm learning React from self learning and need help below for a task. Please apologise for my poor code, still learning.

The main focus of this is trying to use this.setState to push the contents I have gathered from the JSON file to my state as shown below.

(please notice that the list state was a test to see if I was using this.setState correctly) (comments are things I have tried but found they have not given me the result I was looking for)

import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component { constructor(props) { super(props); this.state = { items: [], titles: [], list: [1, 2, 3], } //this.getFlickrApi = this.getFlickrApi.bind(this); }

I'm currently trying to create a simple app that displays pictures from Flickr. Currently using the API URL: https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&&nojsoncallback=1

I'm connecting to this with the code below

```
 componentDidMount() { var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

   request.open('GET', 
  'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne? 
   format=json&&nojsoncallback=1', true);
  var dataOutput = request.onload = function() {

    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    console.log('Before JSON.parse');
    var data = JSON.parse(request.response);
    console.log(data);
    //this.setState({ items: data.items })

    console.log('After JSON.parse');

} else {
    console.log('error');
}
dataOutput = data;

console.log(dataOutput.items[1].title)
//dataOutput.items.forEach()
//this.setState({items: dataOutput.items});
```

}

request.send();

}

And I'm trying to use this to display the 'titles' of each 'item' within the render function.

render() {

```
// Use below for a function
// data.items.forEach(item => {

//     console.log(item.title)


//     //this.setState({titles: data.items.titles})
//     //console.log(this.state.titles)
// });
//console.log(this.state);
//console.log(getFlickrApi());
// {this.getFlickrApi()}

return (
  <div className="FlickrApiContainer">


    ))}
  {this.state.items.map(item => (<li key={item}>{item.title}</li>))}
  {this.renderItems()}


  </div>
);
```

}

}

But it's not displaying within the list tags despite I can console to it.

Any help appreciated.

Kind regards,

Sam

Comment: Where are you setting the state

Comment: There are two commented out lines with this.setState within render() and the other one is in ComponentDidMount. Both didn't work for me, however I'm finding that pushing a json's contents into State is proving more difficult as opposed to just a string.

Like I said, I'm a beginner so I'm still learning react, I just need a nudge in the right direction, so unsure whether you can put setState in render/componentDidMount.

Answer (score 0):

I was not using an arrowhead function in request.onload. As soon as I did and changed it from

var dataOutput = request.onload = function() {

to

var dataOutput = request.onload = () => {

it started to populate the list items with the titles of each item.